# Building an bijection between the orbit of u and the cosets of the stabilizer of u

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

The exercise does not have a solution included, so I'd be thankful, if people here can verify my solution and/or fill any gaps I might have. Also it'd be great if someone could point out a way to shorten the proof.

**So here goes my interpretation of the statement I am trying to prove:**

Let $A$ be any non-empty set.
Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S(A)$, ie. group of permutations on $G$

Let $O: A \rightarrow P(A)$ such that $O(u) = \{g(u) : g \in G\}$. We will call it the **orbit** of u.
Hence $O(u) \subseteq A$.

Let $C: A \rightarrow P(G)$ such that $C(u) = \{g \in G : g(u) = u \}$. We will call it the **stabilizer** of u. Hence $C(u) \subseteq G$.

We want to prove that $|O(u)|=|G|/|C(u)|$.

Since $|G|/|C(u)|$ is the number of cosets of $C(u)$, then it will suffice to prove that there is a onto function from $O(u)$ to the set of cosets of $C(u)$ in G.

Which can be written as  $\exists f$ such that $f_{u}: O(u) \rightarrow G \backslash C(u)$ and is onto.

**Proof:**

Let $f_{u}: O(u) \rightarrow G \backslash C(u)$ and let $f_{u}(k) = gC(u) : g(u) = k$

We want to look at set $\{gC(u) : g(u) = k\}$ and prove that it has exactly one element.

Suppose we have $g,n : g(u) = k,n(u) = k$, we need to prove that $gC(u) = nC(u)$.

Since we're talking about cosets, it will suffice to prove that $g^{-1}n \in C(u)$.
Which is equivalent to $g^{-1}n(u) = u$.

Now $n(u)=k$ and $g^{-1}(k)=u$ since $g(u)=k$. Hence $g^{-1}n(u) = u$ and $gC(u) = nC(u)$.

Now we know that $f_{u}$ is well defined.

Now we need to verify that it's injective and surjective.

Suppose that $f_{u}(k)=f_{u}(t) : k \neq t$.

Then $gC(u) : g(u)=k$ and $pC(u) : p(u)=t$.

If $gC(u)=pC(u)$ then $g^{-1}p \in C(u)$ $<=>$ $g^{-1}p(u) = u$.

But $p(u)=t$ and $g^{-1}(t) \neq u$ because $g^{-1}(k) = u$.

Hence we have a contradiction and $f_{u}$ is injective.

Now to check the surjectivity part.

Lets take a sample coset of $C(u)$, $gC(u)$,
we know that g(u) is well-defined. Let g(u)=k.
Then $f_{u}(k)=gC(u)$ by definition.

Hence $f_{u}$ is surjective.

Comment: See **Theorem 2.98** of p.102 of Rotman's, *"Advanced Modern Algebra"*.

Comment: Thanks, I will look it up.

Comment: I see, so in the book, it's built in reverse: $f_{u}: G \backslash C(u)  \rightarrow O(u)$. But it mostly looks the same, though it was harder for me to follow because it had some steps omitted(probably trivial for an Advanced Algebra book).

Comment: You're welcome. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem) for some easier proofs of the orbit-stabiliser theorem.